# Using FireBase, how can I check if an username it its available for signing up?

Tags: firebase, nosql

Hello this is a silly and simple question

I know that FireBase Auth does not storage any type of username.

So what should I do, storage all the username in a file in FileStorage, and then check for a match, Wouldn't that take too long?

Any documentation or guide will help a lot
Thank you!

Comment: The idiomatic is to store a username for each user in a database (such as Firebase's Realtime Database or Firestore). By using the name as the key or document ID, you can ensure only one user can claim each name. This has been covered quite a few times already, so I recommend checking out some of the answers from this list: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+unique+username